# Is it safe to move a file before closing it?

Tags: python

I want to create a file, write to it and then move it somewhere else. Is it okay to do the move operation in the scope of the `with` block, before the file is closed?

```
from pathlib import Path
my_file = Path("some_file.txt")    
with open(my_file, "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write("some stuff\n")
    Path(outfile.name).replace(Path.home / "my_file")
```

Or could this produce some sort of race condition?

The reason I want to do this is because I want to process a file by first writing to a `NamedTemporaryFile` and then replacing my original file with it, so that if I have an unhandled exception during processing I don't end up with an incomplete file. If I want to move the file outside the `with` statement I have to use an extra line for remembering the file path.

```
from pathlib import Path
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

my_file = Path("aoeu.txt")

with open(my_file) as infile:
    with NamedTemporaryFile("w", delete=False) as outfile:
        for line in infile:
            outfile.write(do_some_stuff(line))
        new_filename = outfile.name
Path(new_filename).replace(my_file)
```

Comment: *"If I want to move the file outside the `with` statement I have to use an extra line for remembering the file path."* What? No you don't. Where did you get that idea?

Comment: @Aran-Fey thanks, I didn't realize `outfile` would still exist outside the `with` block.

Comment: @Boris: That's what the `delete=False` does.

Comment: @martineau no, I didn't realize variables created in the actual `with` statement exist outside it, but it makes sense if variables created inside the statement exist outside it.

Comment: @Boris: All `with` statements do is automatically close the context manager object at the end of the block (and have little to do with the lifespan of variables or file-system objects).